# Configuring SpringSecurity 3.2.5 Multiple http tag for different login page

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently exploring the possibility of having two separate log in page for different users.

I am now able to to set most urls according to the two pages. However, i am now having a configuration issue for the entry-point-ref and CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER.

As for this security version, ( LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.class - loginFormUrl ConcurrentSessionFilter.class - expiredUrl ) the setter method for the property are deprecated, left with the constructor injection that is set in the xml.

So I am thinking of two ways to solve this problem:
1. Override or Inject the two classes and change the url base on condition ?
2. Write a seperate http tag that reads in the specific url pattern and apply the configurations accordingly.

Thanks in advance. The working code is below:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />  
<security:http auto-config="false"  use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" requires-channel="any"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.json*" requires-channel="any"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/dashboard/**" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/rest/**" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/cart/**" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/customer/**" requires-channel="any"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/api/**" requires-channel="any"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/signin" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/signup" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/signin" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/signup" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customDeveloperPasswordAutenticationFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"/>
    <security:logout  logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"  success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
</security:http>
```

The code i'm trying to achieve is:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />  
<security:http auto-config="false"  use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" requires-channel="any"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.json*" requires-channel="any"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/dashboard/**" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/cart/**" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/customer/**" requires-channel="any"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/api/**" requires-channel="any"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/signin" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/signup" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"/>
    <security:logout  logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout_user"  success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandlerUser"/>
</security:http> 

<security:http auto-config="false"  use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/rest/**" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/signin" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/signup" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="restConcurrencyFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customDeveloperPasswordAutenticationFilter"/>
    <security:logout  logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout_developer"  success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandlerDeveloper"/>
</security:http> 

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="customPasswordEncoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id='customUserDetailsService' class='sg.oddlefnb.common.security.CustomUserDetailServiceImpl'>
    <!-- use to DAO to switch for different condition -->
    <property name='userDao' ref='userDao' />  
    <property name='developerDao' ref='developerDao' />  
</bean>
```

However, this could not run.. Any advice?

Comment: It's easy if you will separate http tag, rather than change the url based on condition.

Comment: yup.. however, i tried a few times and i'm not sure what's the problem, it just couldnt configured well..

Comment: can you post what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to do it that way, it is not the *spring security way*. Maybe  you could succeed (even if I doubt you can ...) but it will be hard to write and to maintain.

You can have multiple `<http>` blocs in a single config, but it is when you want to apply different filter chains to different URL blocs.

You may have different login pages (and also different authentication methods : login page, basic authentication, ldap, custom ...). But the spring way is to separate authentication and access control. So when a user is authenticated, his authentication is stored in session and will be used for all following requests (until end of session). In your example if someone asks for a user page before authentication, if will be redirected to user login page, authenticated as a user and he will get its page. But if he asks for a developper page on next request, spring security will find a valid authentication in session a permitAll as access rule and will allow the page ... which I assume is not what you want !

The spring security way to do what you want is to use roles. The simple way is to have one single page, and store the roles in a database (or in a in-memory store for developpement and tests). You the use the roles in the access rules. You will find many examples for that in Spring Security Reference Manual.

Edit per OP comment :

It is rather uncommon to assign roles depending on used login page, but it can be done. You simply need to define two different `AuthenticationManager` beans, and explicitely assign them to the two different `<http>` blocs where you declare your login pages. In one you explicitely affect a `ROLE_USER` granted authority, and in the other a `ROLE_DEVELOPPER` one. You may do it *by hand* by subclassing a `ProviderManager` and using same `AuthenticationProviderS` in both, or you can use plain `ProviderManager` and customize the `UserDetailsService` beans of the `AuthenticationProviderS`. If you showed your current `<authentication-manager>` bloc, I could easily propose a full solution.

Once you have different roles, it is easy to put all access control in one single `<http>` bloc, with all the `<security:intercept-url .../>` inside it.

Comment: Thank you to indicate out this issue, however, in my situation, both normal user and developer may use the same email address. This is way i am trying to differentiate out the two log in page instead of assign them roles.